# How can I get the first result for each account in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that follows this logic:

*Find the first following status code of an account that had a previous status code of X.*

So if I have a table of:

```
id    account_num    status_code
64        1               X
82        1               Y
72        2               Y
87        1               Z
91        2               X
103       2               Z
```

The results would be:

```
id   account_num     status_code
82        1               Y
103       2               Z
```

I've come up with a couple of solutions but I'm not all that great with SQL and so they've been pretty inelegeant thus far. I was hoping that someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

View:

```
SELECT account_number, id
FROM   table
WHERE  status_code = 'X'
```

Query:

```
SELECT account_number, min(id)
FROM   table
INNER JOIN view
ON table.account_number = view.account_number
WHERE table.id > view.id
```

At this point I have the id that I need but I'd have to write ANOTHER query that uses the id tolook up the status_code.

**Edit:** To add some context, I'm trying to find calls that have a status_code of X. If a call has a status_code of X we want to dial it a different way the next time we make an attempt. The aim of this query is to provide a report that will show the results of the second dial if the first dial resulted an X status code.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: It appears that you're making the assumption that the higher id numbers come after the lower id numbers?  Also, can an account have a status_code of X more than once?  If so, how should it be handled?  Should each record that comes after a status_code of X be shown, or just the first or the last?

Comment: what does `following` and `previous` mean, is there a row that defines the order ?

Comment: @Forester93 Yes, higher id numbers always come after lower id numbers. The status_code of X can happen more than once but in this case we're looking for the FIRST occurance of it. Once the first occurance is found we want to know what the following status_code was (if there is one).

Comment: @KuyaJohn No, we only care about the status_code immediately following X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a SQL Server solution.

**UPDATE**

The idea is to avoid a number of NESTED LOOP joins as proposed by Olaf because they roughly have O(N * M) complexity and thus extremely bad for your performance. MERGED JOINS complexity is O(N*Log(N) + M*Log(M)) which is much better for real world scenarios.

The query below works as follows:

`RankedCTE` is a subquery that assigns a row number to each id partioned by account and sorted by id which represents the time. So for the data below the output of this

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    account_num, 
    status_code,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_num ORDER BY id DESC) AS item_rank
FROM dbo.Test
```

would be:

```
id          account_num status_code item_rank
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
87          1           Z           1
82          1           Y           2
64          1           X           3
103         2           Z           1
91          2           X           2
72          2           Y           3
```

Once we have them numbered we join the result on itself like this:

```
WITH RankedCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        account_num, 
        status_code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_num ORDER BY id DESC) AS item_rank
    FROM dbo.Test
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    RankedCTE A
    INNER JOIN RankedCTE B ON 
            A.account_num = B.account_num
            AND A.item_rank = B.item_rank - 1
```

which will give us an event and a preceding event in the same table

```
id          account_num status_code item_rank   id          account_num status_code item_rank
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
87          1           Z           1           82          1           Y           2
82          1           Y           2           64          1           X           3
103         2           Z           1           91          2           X           2
91          2           X           2           72          2           Y           3
```

Finally, we just have to take the preceding event with code "X" and the event with code *not* "X":

```
    WITH RankedCTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            account_num, 
            status_code,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_num ORDER BY id DESC) AS item_rank
        FROM dbo.Test
    )
    SELECT 
        A.id, 
        A.account_num, 
        A.status_code
    FROM 
        RankedCTE A
        INNER JOIN RankedCTE B ON 
            A.account_num = B.account_num
            AND A.item_rank = B.item_rank - 1
            AND A.status_code <> 'X'
            AND B.status_code = 'X'
```

Query plans for this query and @Olaf Dietsche solution (one of the versions) are below.

[image: query plans]

Data setup script

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    account_num int not null,
    status_code nchar(1)
)
GO

INSERT dbo.Test (id, account_num, status_code)
SELECT 64 ,       1,               'X' UNION ALL
SELECT 82 ,       1,               'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 72 ,       2,               'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 87 ,       1,               'Z' UNION ALL
SELECT 91 ,       2,               'X' UNION ALL
SELECT 103,       2,               'Z'
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort that you put into this but I must admit that I don't really know what you're doing in your query.

Comment: @Kittoes That's all right, I've updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this also looks like it'd work if the status code of the second event was also X. Meaning that if there was a third event then both the second and third events would end up in the results.

Comment: @Kittoes You're right, thank a lot for spotting my mistake. The fix is not hard, I've updated the post.

Comment: @Kittoes What's the expected result, when you have two or three consecutive 'X'?

Comment: Serge, I'm not entirely sure that that's a mistake. I went with my original criteria because it seemed simplest. Your implementation might be more desirable than what I was asking for. I'm just not sure yet because I'm still trying to iron out the best way we can utilize this report. My manager asked me to build it and the premise for it is really solid but it's important that I give the implementation that returns the results she needs and not necessarily exactly what she asked for. Either way, I appreciate you giving me both versions.

Comment: @OlafDietsche See my comment. In your implementation if two or even three X's are in a row then it returns only the second X. Which was the requested/expected result.

Comment: @Kittoes No worries, solving problems is fun in itself. Good luck with your report!

Comment: @SergeBelov I take it that the line `AND A.status_code <> 'X'` makes the query only return the first result if there are multiple X codes?

Comment: @Kittoes *The line AND A.status_code <> 'X' makes the query only return the first result if there are multiple X codes* - that's true.

Comment: @SergeBelov And just to be sure I'm understanding this right if account 1 has 3 X codes it'll return the SECOND record, right?

Comment: @Kittoes I'm not 100% sure what you mean and the logic might need yet additional testing, but I'd put it in this way: if you have several consecutive events with code 'X' the query should only return the first following one.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle with subselect](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa842/1/0)

```
select id, account_num, status_code
from mytable
where id in (select min(t1.id)
             from mytable t1
             join mytable t2 on t1.account_num = t2.account_num
                             and t1.id > t2.id
                             and t2.status_code = 'X'
             group by t1.account_num)
```

and [SQL Fiddle with join](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa842/4/0), both for MS SQL Server 2012, both returning the same result.

```
select id, account_num, status_code
from mytable
join (select min(t1.id) as min_id
      from mytable t1
      join mytable t2 on t1.account_num = t2.account_num
                      and t1.id > t2.id
                      and t2.status_code = 'X'
      group by t1.account_num) t on id = min_id
```

Comment: Wouldn't SQL typically complain about status_code not being aggregated or grouped? I can see that it works in your SQL Fiddle but I'm curious as to why.

Comment: @Kittoes Yes, it would. That's why I hinted at MySQL.

Comment: Ah, I'm using SQL Server. That's pretty slick though.

Comment: @Kittoes See updated answer and SQL Fiddle for MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: That picks the min id from the id's larger than the one with the x, however it doesn't mean that it will take the status_code from the same row.  In SQL Server this wouldn't run because you would have to put status_code in an aggregate function or else put it in the group by clause.

Comment: @BrandonMoore Look at the new SQL Fiddle. It runs *and* returns the desired result.

Comment: You would have to join to the table again based on the id's this table returns in order to retrieve the correct status

Comment: @BrandonMoore So, are you saying that if more data was in the table (I.E. if I was doing this with my actual date) that it would return the incorrect status codes? If so, why?

Comment: @Kittoes  It's grouping on the account number.  The select clause indicates that it should take the minimum id from each group.  It doesn't specify which status_code to take from the group though.  You could have selected both min(t1.id) and max(t1.id) in the query... then which status code should it take?  We can infer that you probably want the status code that goes with the row that min(t1.id) comes from but there's nothing in the language specification to tell SQL to do that.

Comment: @Kittoes That's why SQL Server makes you either include fields in an aggregate function, or else include the field in the group by clause.  Otherwise it's really, really easy to make a query that you think is doing what you want when it's really not.

Comment: @BrandonMoore The subselect shouldn't be responsible for selecting the status code though. All it should return is the correct id and then the 'main' select uses that id to look up the account_num and status_code. At least, that's how I understand the query.

Comment: @OlafDietsche  You can see how your query produces an incorrect result here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f60e1/1

Comment: @BrandonMoore Whatever you're trying to show, this is *not* my query. Anyway, I plugged *your* [data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f60e1/1) into *my* [query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c23f/1/0) and the result is correct. Same goes for the [join version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c23f/2)

Comment: @Kittoes This query (minus the status_code) could be used as a subquery to do what you just described... but right now it simply selects a random status_code from the a group containing records for a particular account whose id's are all higher than the record for that account which has an x.

Comment: @BrandonMoore I think you need to look again... The SQL Fiddle query you used is def different than the one Olaf posted.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Huh?  You changed your answer.  Don't be a douche bag and act like you had that up there the whole time.

Comment: @BrandonMoore Relax dude, it's been as he posted for at least 25 minutes.

Comment: @BrandonMoore Of course, I changed it, because my first version was MySQL only and then it turned out it must be for MS SQL Server. But look at the history, I changed it half an hour ago. Anyway, I'm sorry, if it sounded that I wanted to trick you. In the end it seems, we were just talking about different statements. EOT

Comment: @OlafDietsche Sorry man.  You asked me to look at the query 33 mins ago.  I did and when I got back to you about it you say "That's not my query!" instead of "Yeah, you were right and I updated it".  I apologize that that makes me ever so slightly annoyed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), ACCOUNT_NUM, STATUS_CODE FROM (
    SELECT ID,  ACCOUNT_NUM, STATUS_CODE
    FROM ACCOUNT A1
    WHERE EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 
        FROM ACCOUNT A2 
        WHERE A1.ACCOUNT_NUM = A2.ACCOUNT_NUM
         AND A2.STATUS_CODE = 'X'
         AND A2.ID < A1.ID)
    ) SUB
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUM
```

Here's an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf6ec0/15)

Comment: Only 'works' in mySQL (because one column is neither aggregated, nor grouped), and is not guaranteed to always return the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's query, with your data, checked under PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM so13594339 t0 JOIN
 (SELECT min(t1.id), t1.account_num
   FROM so13594339 t1, so13594339 t2
   WHERE t1.account_num = t2.account_num AND t1.id > t2.id AND t2.status_code = 'X'
   GROUP BY t1.account_num
 ) z
 ON t0.id = z.min AND t0.account_num = z.account_num;
```